# PySpark, create line graph from a dataframe without a "category" on databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm running the following code on databricks:

```
dataToShow = jDataJoined.\
withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id()).\
filter( 
  (jDataJoined.containerNumber == 'SUDU8108536')).\
select(col('id'), col('returnTemperature'), col('supplyTemperature'))
```

This will give me tabular data like

[image: tabular data]

Now I would like to display a line graph with this returnTemperature and supplyTemperature as categories.

As far as I understood, the method `display` in databricks wants as second argument the category, so basically what I should have is something like

```
id - temperatureCategory - value
1 - returnTemperature - 25.0
1 - supplyTemperature - 27.0
2 - returnTemperature - 24.0
2 - supplyTemperature - 28.0
```

How can I transform the dataframe in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your format is what the display method is expecting, but you can do this transformation with the sql functions [create_map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) and [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode):

```
#creates a example df
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
l1 = [(1,25.0,27.0),(2,24.0,28.0)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l1,['id','returnTemperature','supplyTemperature'])

#creates a map column which contains the values of the returnTemperature and supplyTemperature
df = df.withColumn('mapCol', F.create_map(
                                    F.lit('returnTemperature'),df.returnTemperature
                                    ,F.lit('supplyTemperature'),df.supplyTemperature
                                   ) 
                  )
#The explode function creates a new row for each element of the map
df = df.select('id',F.explode(df.mapCol).alias('temperatureCategory','value'))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+-----+ 
| id|temperatureCategory|value| 
+---+-------------------+-----+ 
| 1 |  returnTemperature| 25.0| 
| 1 |  supplyTemperature| 27.0| 
| 2 |  returnTemperature| 24.0| 
| 2 |  supplyTemperature| 28.0| 
+---+-------------------+-----+
```